# Angularjs apply color on selected range in table

Tags: javascript, angularjs

I have a **custom slider (HTML5 custom slider)** and as seen below, I use it to select a number of hours before `ng-click`'ing on one of the table cells. On clicking a table cell (11 am) the selected range of hours(3) should render as green with '**Selected**' as text.

[image]

How do I achieve this?

```
    <tbody>
        <tr ng-repeat="hour in workhours">
            <td >{{hour}}:00 - {{hour+1}}:00</td>
            <td ng-class = "{'full' : !entry.HoursAvailable.includes(hour)}" 
                ng-click = "checkSlotAvailability(hour, jobLength, entry, data)"
                ng-repeat= "entry in data.calendar">
                    <span ng-if="entry.HoursAvailable.includes(hour)"> 
                        {{ data.response }}
                    </span>
                    <span ng-if="!entry.HoursAvailable.includes(hour)">
                        FULL
                    </span>
            </td>
        </tr>
    </tbody>
```

Comment: Is jobLength the value of slider? For instance 3 from your above example?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Assuming `jobLength` is the value from the slider, you can pass the corresponding index of the row item which is clicked and capture all the required index by incrementing it till `jobLength`

**HTML**:

```
   <tbody>
<tr ng-repeat="hour in workhours" ng-init="selectedIndex=$index">
    <td>{{hour}}:00 - {{hour+1}}:00</td>
    <td ng-click="checkSlotAvailability(hour, jobLength, entry, data,selectedIndex,$index)" ng-repeat="entry in data.calendar" ng-class="{'full' : !entry.HoursAvailable.includes(hour),'selected':selectedIndex==selectedRow && $index<=selectedColumn+jobLength-1}">
        <span ng-if="entry.HoursAvailable.includes(hour)&&!checkSelected(selectedIndex, $index,jobLength) "> 
                    {{ data.response }}
                </span>
        <span ng-if="entry.HoursAvailable.includes(hour)&&checkSelected(selectedIndex, $index,jobLength) "> 
                    Selected
                </span>
        <span ng-if="!entry.HoursAvailable.includes(hour)">
                    FULL
                </span>
    </td>
</tr>
```

**JS**

```
$scope.selectedArray=[];
$scope.checkSlotAvailability=function(hour, jobLength, entry, data,selectedIndex,index){
$scope.selectedRow=selectedIndex;
$scope.selectedColumn=index;

}
```

**CSS**

```
.selected{
 background-color:green;
}
```

You can maybe write a function to evaluate the logic for your `ng-class`

```
 $scope.checkSelected = function(selectedIndex, index,jobLength) {
     if (selectedIndex == $scope.selectedRow && (index <= ($scope.selectedColumn + jobLength - 1))) 
       return true
     else 
       return false;
 }
```

Comment: thanks. the color is rendered correctly for the time and jobLength selected but it spans across all the days. How can I target the particular day?

Comment: You are telling that it is spanning across all the days of the week but you want it for that particular day?

Comment: I am now having a syntax error in the html where the `&&` is. How come I can't place 2 conditions on my side. Your's works?

Comment: @colin_dev256 Try the above way without ant brackets in ng-class and also if that doesn't work try abstracting the logic into a function like above

Comment: thanks managed to fiddle around with it after understanding how it works it managed to get it rendering the color the way I wanted. You forgot to show me how to change the text(when response changes for example). how do I get it to display 'Selected' as shown in the snap shot. that should be easy but when I try, the cells change text.

Comment: Yeah I forgot. I have updated my answer with text change. You just have to check for the same condition that triggers the color change of cell to green in your ng-if. Please accept or upvote  answer if it was helpful :)